# Leaflet plot with GPS coordinates in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I want to display a CSV file via its coordinates using `leaflet` in `R`. I think `leaflet` is not being able to pick up the coordinates correctly, how can I fix this?

Sample Data

```
Point Name X        Y
1     A    1393959  406726.6
2     B    1392820  407719.7
3     C    1394466  405740.5 
4     D    1393543  407094.7
5     E    1395119  405969.7
6     F    1393557  406747.5
```

Code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

map_data = df
map_data$popup = paste("<b>Location #: </b>", map_data$Point,
                       "<br>", "<b>Longitude: </b>", map_data$X,
                    "<br>", "<b>Latitude: </b>", map_data$Y,
                    "<br>", "<b>Desciption </b>", map_data$Name)
                    
                    
leaflet(map_data, width = "100%") %>% addTiles() %>%
  addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "Esri.WorldStreetMap",group = "World StreetMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "Esri.WorldImagery",group = "World Imagery") %>%
  addMarkers(lng = ~X, lat = ~Y, popup = map_data$popup, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

Current Plot

[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to convert your coordinate system from x, y to longitude & latitude.  The rgdal or sf packages can do that.

Comment: @Dave2e, thanks, problem is I don't have the original CRS info, so I don't know if I can reproject without knowing the original CRS.

Comment: most probably you can't. But (maybe) you can try to suppose the CRS based on origin of the datas, what is your country or original country of your data?

Comment: It's in Pennsylvania, USA.

Comment: You can try CRS 2272, this might be a good start.  See this website for more information: https://epsg.io/2272

Comment: @Dave2e, yep that worked thank you, can you please look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69415642/st-read-path-for-shinyapp-in-r) too? I am basically stuck at defining a proper `dsn` while using `st_read` in a `shiny` app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the `df` into an `sf` object. Define the `CRS` which in my case is `2271`. Reproject to `4326` to make it work with `leaflet` and run the rest of the code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)
library(leaflet)

# Convert df to sf
df_sf = st_as_sf(x = df,                         
           coords = c("X", "Y"),
           crs = 2271)

# Reproject to WGS84
df_sf = st_transform(df_sf , 4326)
df_sf = sf_to_df(rocks_wgs_sf, fill = T) 

# Create the map
map_data = df
map_data$popup = paste("<b>Location #: </b>", map_data$Point,
                       "<br>", "<b>Longitude: </b>", map_data$X,
                    "<br>", "<b>Latitude: </b>", map_data$Y,
                    "<br>", "<b>Desciption </b>", map_data$Name)
                    
                    
leaflet(map_data, width = "100%") %>% addTiles() %>%
  addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "Esri.WorldStreetMap",group = "World StreetMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "Esri.WorldImagery",group = "World Imagery") %>%
  addMarkers(lng = ~X, lat = ~Y, popup = map_data$popup, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```