# st_read path for shinyapp in R

Tags: r, shiny, r-sf

Usually when `st_read` is used you put path in `dsn`, but in case of shiny if you put a full path inside `dsn` it will give an error as that file path does not exist on the server. So, now I put the shapefile in the `www` folder, but I don't know what path to put in `dsn` so that the app picks up the shapefile.

How can I fix this?

Current function code in the app:

```
rocks_utm_sf = st_read(dsn = "D:/Sedimentary_Data_Analysis/www",layer = "Sed_UTM")
```

Below error in the log breaks the app

```
    021-10-02T19:05:08.733697+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: Server version: 1.8.6.1
2021-10-02T19:05:08.733707+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: R version: 4.0.2
2021-10-02T19:05:08.733705+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2021-10-02T19:05:08.725767+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: Running on host: 52b53ce9aed0
2021-10-02T19:05:08.733716+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: shiny version: 1.6.0
2021-10-02T19:05:08.733732+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: httpuv version: 1.6.1
2021-10-02T19:05:08.931183+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2021-10-02T19:05:08.934357+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: 
2021-10-02T19:05:08.733977+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.11
2021-10-02T19:05:08.733739+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: rmarkdown version: 2.9
2021-10-02T19:05:08.733790+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: jsonlite version: 1.7.2
2021-10-02T19:05:08.934357+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: Starting R with process ID: '26'
2021-10-02T19:05:08.733779+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: knitr version: 1.33
2021-10-02T19:05:08.963216+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: 
2021-10-02T19:05:08.733791+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2021-10-02T19:05:08.733797+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: htmltools version: 0.5.1.1
2021-10-02T19:05:08.963841+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]:     box
2021-10-02T19:05:08.963217+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: 
2021-10-02T19:05:08.963840+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:
2021-10-02T19:05:08.963840+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: 
2021-10-02T19:05:08.963217+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’
2021-10-02T19:05:08.963841+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: 
2021-10-02T19:05:10.008023+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.1 ──
2021-10-02T19:05:10.013142+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: ✔ ggplot2 3.3.5     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
2021-10-02T19:05:10.013143+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: ✔ tibble  3.1.3     ✔ dplyr   1.0.7
2021-10-02T19:05:10.013144+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: ✔ tidyr   1.1.3     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
2021-10-02T19:05:10.194146+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
2021-10-02T19:05:10.194148+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
2021-10-02T19:05:10.013144+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: ✔ readr   2.0.0     ✔ forcats 0.5.1
2021-10-02T19:05:10.194148+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
2021-10-02T19:05:10.415161+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
2021-10-02T19:05:10.464817+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:44842
2021-10-02T19:05:10.464815+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: 
2021-10-02T19:05:16.625537+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]: Warning: Error in : Cannot open "D:/Sedimentary_Data_Analysis/www"; The file doesn't seem to exist.
2021-10-02T19:05:16.630916+00:00 shinyapps[4783188]:   113: <Anonymous>
```

Comment: Does your shiny App run inside a shiny R project template .Rproj? I have not problem with that, just writing: `data.p <- st_read('deps.geojson')` for instance, where deps.geojson is in the app dir, with app.R (or ui.R and server.R), not using system file.

Comment: Yes, I am using the usual shiny template i.e. load the packages, define UI, define the server and run the app. I don't know about .Rproj. The app file itself is app.r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Guillaumme for his comment, so I was able to fix the problem by first moving the `shiny` app to a `R` project. Then in the `app` code write `st_read` as follows, and the app is able to pick up the shapefile when its published on `shinyapps.io`.

```
 sf_object = st_read(dsn = "www", layer = "Name")
```